# perl regex works in script but not when executed on the command line

Tags: regex, perl, command-line

I'm trying to manipulate multiline CoffeeScript comments in a file using perl.  This is my regex:

```
^\t*###[\S\s]*?^\t*###
```

When I run this in a script where data is the file data, it does what I expect and replaces all multiline comments with "foo":

```
$data =~ s{^\t*###[\S\s]*?^\t*###}{"foo"}gme;
```

However, when I run this on the command line the file is unchanged:

```
perl -pi -e 's{^\t*###[\S\s]*?^\t*###}{"foo"}gme' file.coffee
```

I've used similar commands with different regular expressions and without the 'm' option and they all work.  Is it the m option that's causing the issue?  I'm sure its something simple.

Comment: I'm curious if the filesystem is taking the `\t` as a literal tab char instead of the actual regex tab? What happens if you try escaping the backslashes?

Comment: Escape the backslashes as `\\t`?

Comment: Yeah, give that a shot. No idea if it'll work though :)

Comment: I ran `perl -pi -e 's{^\\t*###[\S\s]*?^\\t*###}{"foo"}gme' file.coffee` and still no joy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the implicit loops set by `-n` and `-p` it can be useful to define the values of `$/` and `$\`. Using the `-0` option puts Perl in paragraph mode and the special value `0777` puts Perl into file slurp mode.

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's{^\t*###[\S\s]*?^\t*###}{"foo"}gme' file.coffee
```

Comment: Thanks for putting this up as an answer for anyone who stumbles across this question.

Answer (score 3):

The perl documentation for the `-n`/`-p` option states:

```
assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program
```

This means that each time the `-e` expression is executed, `$_` is one line of the input file. Your `s///` expression is expecting to operate on the whole entire file at once, so it won't work in this mode.

Comment: Is there any way I can operate on the whole file at once from the command line?

Comment: Not in-place that I can find, but you could probably do something like: `perl -e 'local $/; $data = <>; $data =~ s/find/replace/; print $data' < file > file.new && mv file.new file`

Comment: @RyanLynch You can slurp the file.

Comment: Thanks @hwnd. I'll think about asking another question now that I know what the issue is.

Comment: Try this `perl -0777 -i -pe 's{^\t*###[\S\s]*?^\t*###}{"foo"}gme' file.coffee`

Comment: Hey @AndrewMedico, thanks for this answer, it definitely pointed me in the right direction. I changed the correct answer for this question though since the other solved the issue better.